# How to skip a header after regex match and read next line using BufferReader

Tags: java, regex

I have a stream which continue to print rows as follows:

```
11:19:54 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
11:19:55 AM     all      0.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     99.00
Average:        all      0.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     99.00

11:19:55 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
11:19:56 AM     all      0.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     99.00
Average:        all      0.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     99.00
```

....so on

Java Code is:

```
    public final static String REGEX_STARTS_WITH_TIME = "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\s+[A-Z]{2}\\s";
    public final static String REGEX =  REGEX_STARTS_WITH_TIME + "CPU\\s+%usr\\s";
    String line;
    try {
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();                
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line.matches(REGEX);
         //Here I want to read the next line by skipping the header.
        }        
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ......
    }
```

I want to skip the header and read only next line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string#contains("CPU")` to check if the line contains that sub-string. If it does, (then it is a header,) just call `continue` in the loop.

Side note : This can be achieved using `indexOf()` as well. I don't see any reason to use regex here
.

Comment: `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s+[A-Z]{2}\s*(all)` , how about this that just matches the lines having only the all word preceded by a time stamp ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 - Using regex is less efficient than using `contains()`. Yes, your approach would work too :)